# Работа модуля getopt в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, getopt

Прошу объяснить пример из стандартной документации python [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/getopt.html) .

```
import getopt, sys
def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "ho:v", ["help", "output="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        # print help information and exit:
        print(err) # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    output = None
    verbose = False
    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "-v":
            verbose = True
        elif o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif o in ("-o", "--output"):
            output = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

В частности откуда взять функцию `usage()`?
Почему такие разные параметры `sys.exit()` и `sys.exit(2)`?
Какую роль выполняет переменная `verbose`?
Что делает команда `assert False ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usage` - это просто функция, которая выводит список аргументов и краткое описание, как их использовать. Пишется самостоятельно (да, имя можно свое взять).

Параметр `-v` часто используется для двух вещей - либо вывести версию приложения, либо "усилить вывод". В данном примере используется для второго. Суть в том, что если `verbose == False`, то программа выводит мало сообщений, а при `True` - больше. Удобно для отладки. Некоторые консольные утилиты используют ещё параметры вида `-vv` и `-vvv` для ещё более подробного вывода в лог. Опять же все реализуется программистом в коде, ибо только он знает, какие сообщения важные, а какие менее.

Параметры, которые использованы в данном примере насколько часто используются в консольных приложениях в Linux (да и не только), что у многих они даже не вызывают никаких вопросов их имена и назначения:)

`sys.exit()` - это завершить программу. Досрочно. А аргумент в скобках - это то, что возвратить операционной системе. Дело в том, что в Linux (и Windows тоже) принято, что если программа завершает работу нормально, то она должна возвратить ноль. В противном случае - какое то число. (и это число в диапазоне от 0 до 127, если мне не изменяет память). По этому коду другие программы, которые запускали данную могут судить о результатах ее работы. Что значит любое число, отличное от нуля - на выбор создателя программы и это описывается в документации (но не всегда).

И самое последнее - `assert False, "unhandled option"` - а вот это уже немного странный код, но абсолютно законный. assert принимает два аргумента - булево выражение и строку. Если выражение равно True, то ничего не делается. Если же False (как в данном случае), то заданная строка выводиться пользователю (например, в терминал) и работа программы прекращается. Обычно assert (которое следует читать так "утверждаю, что в данной строке следующее выражение истинно, и если это не так, вывести указанное сообщение и закрешиться") применяют там, где нужно проверить правильность поведения программы. если кратко, то assert можно перевести на код где то так (реализии могут сильно отличаться)

```
def assert(cond, message):
    if not cond:
        print message
        sys.exit(1)
```

но вот только компилятор и библиотека знают об этой функции и могут сделать больше - вывести стектрейс или вызвать отладчик (все сильно зависит от языка и среды).

Comment: Приблизили меня к пониманию. Спасибо :) А как определить обязателен ли параметр к вводу, например, output? Путём добавления знака '='

Comment: А как определить обязателен параметр или нет? Например,  'output', путём добавления знака '='?

Comment: Никак. Optional arguments are not supported. Используйте другую библиотеку

Comment: @KoVadim А почему вам тут `assert` показался странным? Вроде нормальная заглушка на случай если забыли сделать обработку какой-то опции.

Comment: потому что `assert False`. Страшнее только `assert True`:) я честно ожидал что то вида `raise Exception('unhandled option')` `die` в питоне нет.